# Convert day of the year to date with QT

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am facing an issue, the API that I am using return the year and the day of the year.
For example : `year = 2020 & day = 328` and I should be able to convert it to **24/11/2020**.
I saw that QT implements a method called **"daysInYear"** in QDate which looks like to do the exact opposite of what I need.
Does anyone knows a method in QT or Cpp11+ which can do the job ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: QDate has a `addDays` method, so start from Jan 1, 2020 and add 328-1 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can write that to obtain what you desire:

```
QDate(year, 1, 1).addDays(day); // or addDays(day - 1) if your `day` starts at 1.
```

But make sure to do a small test to check that it is correct, depending on whether your `day` equals `0` or `1` on January 1st !

CAUTION: `daysInYear()` returns the total number of days for a given year, e.g. 365 or 366, while `dayOfYear()` returns the opposite of what you want.